# webkit inspector losing network data on page change

Tags: webkit, inspector

In Safari and Chrome I lose all my network data in the inspector when the page URL changes -- how can I keep that data around long enough to catch what I need / refer back to that data even after the URL changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While on the network tab, there is a black circle in the bottom toolbar (near the left side). This button allows you to preserve all the data until you clear it (by clicking the open circle with the diagonal line through it) or close the inspector. Click the button and the circle will turn red indicating that all of the data is being recorded. You will not lose any data that is recorded while the circle is red.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that. Thanks!